# AWS VPN Access to the Internet - What is the public IP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn

this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/scenario-internet.html) is to the standard AWS documentation for connecting Client VPNs to the Internet via a VPC, see the diagram below. But what I don't understand is, in this scenario, what is the public IP of the clients?

The problem I'm trying to solve is connecting a disparate set of clients to the Internet with a single static IP address that can then be whitelisted by a 3rd party whose services I'm trying to access.

This SO post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62084645/public-ip-of-aws-internet-gateway), suggests that there needs to be something in the VPC that has a public IP address; the IGW alone is not enough. That is how I thought it worked, and that I would need to add a NAT instance or something to the VPC for the clients to get to the Internet. But the diagram below (straight from AWS) doesn't have anything that has a public IP assigned in the VPC. Can anyone explain what I'm not understanding? The clients and the VPN are both on non-routable address ranges, so they are no good for presenting to the Internet. The only thing I can think is that the "Client VPN network interface" can have a public IP address assigned, but that isn't mentioned in the documentation. So I'm confused.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A VPN connection is traditionally used to grant access to resources in a private network. It is not normally used to grant access to the Internet.

You could try the following (I have not tested this):

- Put the Client VPN ENI in a **Private Subnet**
- Add a NAT Gateway or NAT Instance in a **Public Subnet**, with an Elastic IP assigned (which is a static IP address)
- Add a **Route Table** entry on the Private Subnet to direct Internet-bound (`0.0.0.0/0`) traffic to the NAT Instance / NAT Gateway

The traffic should 'appear' to be coming from the Elastic IP address.

---

An alternative to the above would be to somehow send traffic to an Amazon EC2 instance that then 'forwards' the traffic to the destination via an Elastic IP address. This might be possible via a HTTPS Squid proxy, or even an SSH Tunnel to the instance. I'm not familiar with how to setup such a system, but there is information available on the web.

Comment: Thanks John, I thought there was a component missing from that picture. I'll let you know how I get on. Technically I think the other options will work too, but I need to control access to the static IP and thought the VPN credentials would be a good way to do this.

Comment: This I tried, I wanted to access the portal hosted on my EC2. I modified my AWS Client VPN setup as suggested above. I had two Subnets, I created one more Route Table added one of the Subnet to another Route Table, added IGW in one of the Route Table, and NAT in one of the Route Table. Connected to my VPN and then tried to access my Portal, unluckily I am not able to access.